# The Chai functions (isAbove, isBelow, ecc) don't works

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to write a test file using Mocha and Chai, but it seems that the Chai libraries don't want to work. I'm surely doing something wrong, but I can't understand where.

This is the code

```
function byte() {}

describe("byteToSignedShort()", function()
{
   context("in b argument with the first bit set to 1", function()
   {
       it("should return a negative number", function()
       {
           assert.isBelow(byte(), 0, "");
       })
   })
   context("in b argument with the first bit set to 0", function()
   {
       it("should return a positive number", function()
       {
           assert.isAtLeast(byte(), 0, "");
       })
   })
})
```

I don't know if it could be useful, but here's the package.json

```
{
  "name": "learing_typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register test/**.ts --recursive --no-deprecation"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/expect": "^24.3.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^8.1.3",
    "ts-mocha": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.11.5"
  }
}
```

And when i launch it with "npm test" gives me this error

```
byteToSignedShort()
    in b argument with the first bit set to 1
      1) should return a negative number
    in b argument with the first bit set to 0
      2) should return a positive number

  0 passing (16ms)
  2 failing

  1) byteToSignedShort()
       in b argument with the first bit set to 1


should return a negative number:
     TypeError: assert.isBelow is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\byteTestDC.ts:10:20)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)

  2) byteToSignedShort()
       in b argument with the first bit set to 0
         should return a positive number:
     TypeError: assert.isAtLeast is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\byteTestDC.ts:17:20)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `assert` import statement from `chai` package

```
import { assert } from 'chai'; // add import statement

function byte() {}

describe("byteToSignedShort()", function()
{
  ...
}
```